# Angular directive execution order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have a number of directives applied to an element in AngularJS, in what order will they be executed?

For example:

```
<input ng-change='foo()' data-number-formatter></input>
```

Will the number formatter or the change event be fired first. Is it deterministic?

Comment: Is the `numberFormatter` directive based on the `$parsers`/`$formatters` chain (as it should be)?

Answer (score 5):

The order in which directives are compiled is directly based on their `priority`:

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element,
>   sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives
>   are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their
>   compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number.
>   Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.
>   Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link
>   functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the
>   same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) says:

> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element,
>   sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives
>   are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their
>   compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number.
>   Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.
>   Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link
>   functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the
>   same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

Also

> **Pre-linking function:** Executed before the child elements are linked.
>   Not safe to do DOM transformation since the compiler linking function
>   will fail to locate the correct elements for linking.
>
> **Post-linking function:** Executed after the child elements are linked.
>   It is safe to do DOM transformation in the post-linking function.

Answer (score 1):

(This question is not about the `priority` setting, it is about the execution of the directives, not the compilation.)

If the `number-formatter` directive is based on the standard `$parsers`/`$formatters` chain, then I believe the order is guaranteed to be formatter/parser first, `ng-change` after. Even if you specify `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'change'}"` the order remains the same.

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4dtnvrbh/ (do experiment with the various `ng-model-options` and watch the console).

Comment: Seems fair to assume the question isn't about priority. Certainly sounds less like it the more I read it, +1

Comment: Actually I had started writing about priority myself, then I noticed the detail!